# SQL PLUS: result not in one entire column

Tags: sql, sqlplus

Don't know why but when I run a query, the result is split in 2 different columns like u see in this

[image: screenshot]

I would like to know how I make these columns one column again.
Also, I'm wondering why the last column name "grade_level" just shows gra and not the full column name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL*Plus, you have to set the column format, size of the line and page as well. In your case you just need to set the size of the page ( / number of records in the page / number of records after which header will be repeated) as follows:

```
set pagesize 200
```

Your column header `GRADE` is not fully visible as maximum data length of this column is less than 5 (`GRADE` - length)

You can use following to format it.

```
column GRADE format a5
```